# Accessing bands of a NetCDF by datetime in Python

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-translate, datetime, band

I want to write each band as a separate file (after `gdal.Translate` operation). So I can directly address to each band by datetime, not by a number?

The second way, more sophisticated is to get all datetimes from file (by `GetMetadata()['NAME_of_Metadata']`) and then make a cycle by this range (indices of the array of dates) and corresponding band numbers - I already done it, but it seems too tricky.